# Can not control iframe height

Tags: css, iframe, height

I faced a strang problem for height of iframe.

In it's parent page, we set it's height = 900px, like that:

```
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
       <?php  include_once "./includes/header.php"; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php include_once "./includes/top.php" ?>
       <?php include_once "./includes/left_nav.php" ?>
       <section id="content">
       <iframe width="100%"  height="900" id="myFrame" src="./modules/ophthalmology/patients.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
       </iframe>
       </section>
       <?php include_once "./includes/footer.php" ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

but it can not show all content inside it. And I checked elements by firebug, then found that:

```
    <iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="208" frameborder="0" src="./modules/ophthalmology/patients.php">
```

The height is changed to 208.

but in another module, its source code:

```
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
       <?php  include_once "./includes/header.php"; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php include_once "./includes/top.php" ?>
       <?php include_once "./includes/left_nav.php" ?>
       <section id="content">
       <iframe width="100%"  height="900" id="myFrame" src="./modules/csvfileupload/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
       </iframe>
       </section>
       <?php include_once "./includes/footer.php" ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

it changed to:

```
    <iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="930" frameborder="0" src="./modules/csvfileupload/index.html">
```

The only difference of these two is src file is different, the first is patients.php, the second is index.html. all others are same.

I have checked the element of content, it's css:

```
    #content {
       border: 1px solid;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
       margin: 0;
       min-height: 600px;
       overflow: visible;
       padding: 15px 5px 15px 230px;
    }
```

And I also found there was a js function in header.php:

```
    function sizeFrame() {
        var F = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        if(F.contentDocument) {
            F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
        } else {
            F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
        }
    }
    window.onload=sizeFrame;
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For an HTML document embedded with `iframe`, your JavaScript code simply adds 30 to the value of the `height` attribute of the `iframe` element. This explains the value 930.  Contrary to what appears to be the goal here, the `scrollHeight` value you get is just the height of the inline frame element, not the intrinsic height requirement of the embedded document.

For an embedded document of a type other than HTML, strange things may happen. For example, if it is a plain text file, the `scrollHeight` value may reflect the intrinsic height requirement, derived from the number of lines in it. Without knowing what the server returns when `./modules/ophthalmology/patients.php` is requested for, I can just guess that it’s something non-HTML.

Comment: I fixed the problem. it was caused by the wrong js code. I removed it, it's ok.